# How to list in a file filenames in ADLS storage folder via LogicApps

Tags: list, azure-blob-storage, filenames, azure-logic-apps

my question is how can I list the filesnames in storage's folder and save them in a file via LogicApps?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried ? Please check [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to write good questions. Also try including the errors or blockers that you are receiving.

Comment: I have a process for moving files from sharepoint to blob and then I want to list filenames for the stored files in blob storage folder in one file via LogicApps

Comment: Please add what you have tried to your question

Comment: I have tried to list the blob then for each taking value, but then don't know how to contunie to store filenames into file in the blob :), added image above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initialize an array and use `Append to array variable` to store the name of the blob inside the array and then use `create Blob` to save the list of files from the required container. Below is the flow of my Logic App.

[image]

**RESULTS:**

***RESULT IN LOGIC APPS***

[image]

***RESULT IN STORAGE ACCOUNT***

[image]